# while projecting on windows 10 to another laptop, this flying windows stays on top, how to disable it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, projector

I can make it "auto-roll-hide", but hovering cursor to its position brings back this window.

Sorry for not proper english.
Thank you in advance.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How are you doing the projecting?

Comment: @harrymc its a windows 10 inbuilt feature